# Showing $K$ is not compact in $l^1$.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $l^1 = \{ \{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty : a_n \in \mathbb{R}, \ \ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| < \infty \}$ and let $K = \{f \in l^1 : |f(k)| \leq \frac{1}{k} \ \ \forall k\}$. Show that $K$ is not compact in $l^1$.

I can't quite finish this up. I'm using the following sequence of sequences: $\{ \{1, 0,0, \dots \}, \{1,\frac{1}{2}, 0, \dots\}, \{1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},0, \dots \}, \dots \}$ i.e, $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{k}$ if $n \le k$ and $f_n(x) =0$ if $n > k$.

I'm trying to show that this goes to infinity in $l^1$, and then showing that no subsequence of it converges to a sequence in $l^1$, but I can't seem to find the right approach. Any nudge in the right direction would be great.

Comment: What does $f(k)$ mean in the definition of $K$? Is it $\sum_n f_nk^n$ or is it $f_k$?

Comment: $f(k)$ is a $kth$ sequence element

Comment: You should be more consistent with the notation. $f_n(x)=1/k$ is surely not what you mean.

Comment: So $f$ is an $\{a_n\}$, and $f(k)$ is $a_k$.

Comment: I see wat you mean. I meant $f_n(k) = 0$ if $n > k$.

Answer (score 2):

Convergence in $\ell^{1}$ implies convergence of the coordinates. If a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ converges, say to $f$, then then we  must have $f(k)=\frac 1 k$ for each $k$ but then $f \notin \ell^{1}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $Y\subset X$ then  for $Y$ to be compact  it is necessary that $Y$ is bounded. That is, it is necessary that $B_d(x,r)\supset Y$ for some $x\in X$ and some $r>0.$   Otherwise, take some  $x=y_1\in Y$  and for $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ take $y_{n+1}\in Y$ with $d(y_1,y_{n+1})>1+\max \{d(y_1,y_j): 1\le j\le n)\}.$ By the triangle inequality, $d(y_i,y_j)>1$ whenever $i\ne j.$ So no subsequence of $(y_n)_{n\in \Bbb Z^+} $ is even a Cauchy sequence.